# memory allocation of the recursive function in recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

This is a simple code of recursion. What I want to know is why I am getting the same memory address for the Reverse function. In my knowledge it should be different each time the function is called. It's not happening here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Reverse();
int main()
{
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    Reverse();
    return 0;
}
void Reverse()
{
    char c;
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if( c != '\n')
    {
        printf("%p\n",Reverse);
        Reverse();
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
123456
```

Output:

```
Enter a sentence: 123456
0x80484be
0x80484be
0x80484be
0x80484be
0x80484be
0x80484be
654321
```

Comment: That is the address of the function `Reverse()`. The function stays put. Only the data it uses can be different.

Comment: Yes..shouldn't the Reverse function have a replica and have different memory assigned each time...

Comment: In each call to the function, the variable `c` is a different one, with a different address. Try printing that address instead: `printf("address of c: %p.\n", (void*)&c);`

Comment: It uses different stack space each time it is called, but the code itself is the same code each time, stored at the same address each time.  If you changed to use `printf("%p\n", (void *)&c);`, you would see the address changing on each invocation.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to do that print, so drawing conclusions from it is kind of shady. That said, it's probably doing what you expect, since (as pointed out by many) *the function* doesn't move when you call it.

Comment: So the thing is the code stays the same...but at each invocation of the function the variables have different memory assigned...but when the last invocation traces back to the second last invocation it gets the same location as the last address of the function...is this right?
and if yes how can i see the stack space (which has an address) being different each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see that the function pointer keeps it's value since the function is physically the same in the code memory of your program.

Remember that when you call a function, along other things, at least the return address is pushed on the stack. So as you call and call and call it again, more and more and yet even more entries will be pushed on the stack, a lot of return addresses along those.

When the function returns, the return address is popped from the stack, so the CPU continues executing stuff after the function call. In the case of recursive functions, this happens multiple times, as long as there are return addresses pointing after the recursive calls, on the stack. Once (when the recursion is over) the stack will deplete, and the last return address will lead the CPU back into your main.

So in short, the stack is what produces the recursion effect, which has nothing much to do with the contents of the code memory.

Comment: can i see the return address being different each time?

Comment: @quidstone: The return addresses during the recursion are the same, since they point at the same instruction in the code memory (except the first, which points into main, eventually leading out of the recursion). Their positions in the stack, that will be which differ! (As I described, there are more and more of those as the recursive calls pile up)